# usar fetch api para apresentar cards de usuarios, innerHTML sobrescreve os cards

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch

Nesse código eu acesso um rest api fake, pego os dados,passo para json, mas na hora de aprensentar os cards dos usuarios não consigo achar uma forma boa para fazer isso, o innerHTML apaga todos os carde e so apresenta o ultimo.

se poder por favor responder em js vanila, mas se nao tiver outro jeito...

e ja aproveitando quais cuidados com segurança eu tenho que tomar nesses casos ?

```js
var button = document.getElementById('load');

button.onclick = async function () {
 /* fake api */
 const url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";  
  
  const elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".card-container");
  const containerEl = document.querySelector(".container");  
  
  await fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json()
    .then(function(myJson){
   
      const data = myJson.data;      
          
      
      /* para cada item cria um card novo na tela */
      data.forEach((item)=>{       
        
        containerEl.innerHTML = 
           '<div class="card-container">'+
             '<img src="'+item.avatar+'" class="card-img"/>'+
             '<h3 class="card-title">'+
             item.first_name +
             '</h3>'+
             '<p card-text>'+
             item.email+
             '</p>'+
           '</div>';          
        
      }) 
      
    })
    )  
  
};
```

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex: 1;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 10vh 0;
}

.card-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  margin-top: 15px;
  
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

.card-container:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- BUTTON TO LOAD CONTENT -->
 <button id="load" type="button">Load all contents</button>
 
  <!-- CARD 1  -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- CARD 2 -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- CARD 3 -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `.innerHTML` substitui todo o conteúdo do elemento por outro código HTML. Como você está usando-o dentro de um `.forEach`, irá restar no elemento apenas o último HTML resultante da última volta do laço, porque os das voltas anteriores serão substituídos.

Uma solução é você declarar uma variável string vazia antes do forEach e dentro do laço ir concatenando o código HTML nessa variável e após concluído o forEach usar o `.innerHTML` para substituir de uma só vez o HTML da div.

Inclua também o código dentro de uma função quando o DOM for carregado para impedir que as variáveis tenham escopo global. Usei abaixo a função do evento `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var button = document.getElementById('load');
   
   button.onclick = async function () {
      /* fake api */
      const url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";  
     
     const elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".card-container");
     const containerEl = document.querySelector(".container");  
     
     await fetch(url)
       .then((resp) => resp.json()
       .then(function(myJson){
   
       let html = ``; // declara variável vazia
            
         const data = myJson.data;      
         
         /* para cada item cria um card novo na tela */
         data.forEach((item)=>{       
           
             // vai concatenando o HTML
             html += '<div class="card-container">'+
             '<img src="'+item.avatar+'" class="card-img"/>'+
             '<h3 class="card-title">'+
             item.first_name +
             '</h3>'+
             '<p card-text>'+
             item.email+
             '</p>'+
           '</div>';          
           
         }) 
         
         containerEl.innerHTML = html; // insere o conteúdo na div
         
       })
       )  
     
   };
});
```

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex: 1;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 10vh 0;
}

.card-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  margin-top: 15px;
  
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

.card-container:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- BUTTON TO LOAD CONTENT -->
 <button id="load" type="button">Load all contents</button>
 
  <!-- CARD 1  -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- CARD 2 -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- CARD 3 -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado, me parece a melhora resposta até agora.

Answer (score 4):

Use o método `.insertAdjacentHTML()` ao invés de `.innerHTML`

O primeiro parametro descreve a posição, use **"afterbegin"** para posicionar antes do primeiro filho.

Se o intuito é adicionar "após", use **"beforeend"** como opção de posição, isso irá adicionar após o ultimo filho.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('load');

button.onclick = async function () {
 /* fake api */
 const url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";  
  
  const elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".card-container");
  const containerEl = document.querySelector(".container");  
  
  await fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json()
    .then(function(myJson){
   
      const data = myJson.data;      
          
      
      /* para cada item cria um card novo na tela */
      data.forEach((item)=>{       
        
        containerEl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="card-container">'+
             '<img src="'+item.avatar+'" class="card-img"/>'+
             '<h3 class="card-title">'+
             item.first_name +
             '</h3>'+
             '<p card-text>'+
             item.email+
             '</p>'+
           '</div>');          
        
      }) 
      
    })
    )  
  
};
```

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex: 1;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 10vh 0;
}

.card-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  margin-top: 15px;
  
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

.card-container:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- BUTTON TO LOAD CONTENT -->
 <button id="load" type="button">Load all contents</button>
 
  <!-- CARD 1  -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- CARD 2 -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- CARD 3 -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <img src="https://visualsound.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/unavailable-image.jpg" width="200px" class="card-img"/>
    <h3 class="card-title">
       TITULO
    </h3>
    <p card-text>
      alguma informação referente a imagem.
    </p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

---

**Referencia**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: otimo cara, respondeu minha duvida bem rapido e simples :) obrigado